# Enviar resultado de una variable que imprime en pantalla a un input hidden

Tags: javascript

me encuentro atascado en un problema, necesito tomar el resultado de las variables **importe** y **ahorro** y enviarlos a los input que están ocultos a la vez que se imprimen en pantalla, para enviarlos a través de un formulario.
He buscado información al respecto pero no logro conseguirlo.
Agradezo mucho cualquier ayuda. Gracias.

```js
// Compara los valores, metros cuadrados y total
document.form.onchange = function(){
 var metrosValor = document.getElementById("metros").value / 10; // Primer valor
 var totalValor = document.getElementById("total").value; // Segundo valor
 
 if(parseInt(metrosValor)>parseInt(totalValor)){
   document.form.comparativa1.value='' + metrosValor + ''; // Primer valor es mas grande que el segundo
 }else if(parseInt(metrosValor)<parseInt(totalValor)){
   document.form.comparativa1.value='' + metrosValor + ''; // Primer valor es mas pequeño que el segundo
 }else{
   document.form.comparativa1.value=''; // Si son iguales no muestra resultado.
 }
}

// Muestra resultado del ahorro, antes de enviar formulario
function resultadoAhorro(){
var comparaMetrosTotal=document.form.comparativa1.value;
var importe=document.form.comparativa1.value*950;
var ahorro=document.form.comparativa1.value*3.8*0.95;
var correo=document.form.email.value;
//var total=document.form.total.value;
//var kWp=document.form.totalkWp.value;
    document.getElementById('mensajeTotalAhorro').innerHTML='<h3 style="font-size:18px"><img src="img/potencia.png">Potencia ofertada: ' + comparaMetrosTotal + ' kWp</h3> <h3 style="font-size:18px"><img src="img/importe.png">Importe de la instalación: ' + importe + ' €</h3> <h3 style="font-size:18px"><img src="img/ahorro.png">Ahorros a futuro: ' + ahorro + ' €</h3> <p>El plazo de amortización para este tipo de instalaciones está entre 5 y 7 años, con una vida útil superior a 25 años. Más información en tu correo ' + correo + '</p><br>';
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="importe" name="Importeinstalación" readonly="readonly">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="ahorro" name="Ahorroaproximado" readonly="readonly">
```

Comment: A parte de que no hace lo que estas pidiendo, que problema hay???

Comment: Creo que no me explico bien, necesito saber como pasar los resultados a los inputs obtenidos de var importe= y var ahorro=

Comment: `document.getElementById('importe')=importe;`
`document.getElementById('ahorro')=ahorro;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despues que haces esto:

```
var importe = document.form.comparativa1.value*950;
var ahorro = document.form.comparativa1.value*3.8*0.95;
```

Pon lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById('importe').value = importe; 
document.getElementById('ahorro').value = ahorro;
```

Luego de obtener el campo de texto, lo que se hace es modificarle su propiedad value, que no es más que establecerle el valor que quieres.

Si tu formulario se llama "form" es decir tiene el atributo name con ese valor, tambien podrias hacerlo de esta manera:

```
document.form.Importeinstalación.value = importe;
document.form.Ahorroaproximado.value = ahorro;
```

Vas accediendo a los componentes a travez de su atributo name, nombre del formulario **form**, acceder a el: **document.form**, nombre del campo de texto correspondiente al importe **Importeinstalación**, acceder a el: **document.form.Importeinstalación**

Espero que te sirva :)

Comment: Efectivamente, muchas gracias a los dos y sobre todo por la explicación Dariel, me a quedado muy claro para seguir aprendiendo!!!

Comment: jajja bien entonces!!!